# The argument type 'Future<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter

i have a problem, i need to make some screen redirect for my flutter apps, but i'm stuck to asigment for home parameter that needed Widget? but i use some chained bool condition, because i'm not using firebase initilization for this app to confirm that use this app running with, because my client not use Google Play Services for their apps

here the root of the project i use to config

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  AppL createState() => AppL();
}

class AppL extends State<App> {
  final deviceStorage = GetStorage();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
  }

  screenRedirect() {
    //Local
    deviceStorage.writeIfNull("isFirstTime", true);
    deviceStorage.read('IsFirstTime') != true
        ? Get.offAll(() => const OnboardingScreen())
        : deviceStorage.read('useradmin')
            ? Get.offAll(() => const NavMenuVisitor())
            : deviceStorage.read('user_login')
                ? Get.offAll(() => const NavMenu())
                : Get.offAll(() => LoginUI());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isFirstTime = deviceStorage.writeIfNull("isFirstTime", true);
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Mobile GKI Indramayu',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: FilemonAppTheme.temaTerang,
      darkTheme: FilemonAppTheme.temaGelap,
      home: isFirstTime
          ? Get.offAll(() => const OnboardingScreen())
          : deviceStorage.read('useradmin')
              ? Get.offAll(() => const NavMenuVisitor())
              : deviceStorage.read('user_login')
                  ? Get.offAll(() => const NavMenu())
                  : Get.offAll(() => LoginUI()),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem appears on this line

```
home: isFirstTime
          ? Get.offAll(() => const OnboardingScreen())
          : deviceStorage.read('useradmin')
              ? Get.offAll(() => const NavMenuVisitor())
              : deviceStorage.read('user_login')
                  ? Get.offAll(() => const NavMenu())
                  : Get.offAll(() => LoginUI()),
```

the function "Screen Redirect" has same effect to direct code inside the home parameter.

i wish i got quick answer, sorry for bad english, i'm not used to type in english.

the result i was expecting is, is there any solution to fix **Widget?** so it can be assign **Future-dynamic-** from the problem i got, or is there any path i can choose to alternated this problem.

Comment: The error is a compile time error indicating you are not using the correct Type. You are calling Get.offAll() which is not a Widget, it is a Function that returns a dynamic Type. Instead of calling Get.offAll(), just return the desired Widget.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie thank you, perhaps i had a burnout, i didn't catch before, again, thank you